# Spring Integration Threads Parked at Service Activator

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, spring-integration

I am having issues with threads getting parked at my Service Activators that leads to files hanging in the SftpGatewayChannel when the pool is depleted. I think it is related to the SA's having a void return, which is correct because they are only incrementing metrics.

I was able to work around the issue by adding a default-reply-timeout to the SftpGateway, but this is not ideal since there is retry advice and I don't want the threads to timeout if there is a connection issue. I would like a solution that returns the threads to the pool after a successful upload and call to the "Success" Service Activator.

```
<task:executor id="Tasker" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" pool-size="${MaxThreads}" />

<int:channel id="SftpGatewayChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="Tasker" />
</int:channel>

<int:service-activator id="SegmentStart" input-channel="SftpGatewayChannel" ref="SftpGateway" />

<int:gateway id="SftpGateway" default-request-channel="SftpOutboundChannel" error-channel="ErrorChannel" />

<int:channel id="SftpOutboundChannel" datatype="java.lang.String,java.io.File,byte[]" />

<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="SftpOutboundAdapter"
    session-factory="SftpCachingSessionFactory" channel="SftpOutboundChannel" charset="UTF-8" >
    <int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <ref bean="exponentialRetryAdvice" />
        <bean id="SuccessAdvice" class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice" >
            <property name="successChannel" ref="SuccessChannel"/>
            <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="ErrorChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="FailureChannel" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="AttemptChannel" />
<int:channel id="SuccessChannel" />
<int:channel id="FailureChannel" />

<int:service-activator id="AttemptMetrics" input-channel="AttemptChannel"
    expression="T(MetricsCounter).addAttempt()"  />
<int:service-activator id="SuccessMetrics" input-channel="SuccessChannel"
    expression="T(MetricsCounter).addSuccesses(inputMessage.Headers.messages.size())" />
<int:service-activator id="FailureMetrics" input-channel="FailureChannel"
    expression="T(MetricsCounter).addFailures(payload.getFailedMessage().Headers.messages.size())" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, gateways expect a reply by default. Instead of using the default `RequestReplyExchanger` you could use a `service-interface` method with a `void` return `void process(Message<?> m)`.

Alternatively, as you have done, simply add `default-reply-timeout="0"` on your gateway and the thread will return immediately without waiting for a reply (that will never come).

> ... but this is not ideal ...

The reply timeout clock only starts when the thread returns to the gateway, so it will have no impact on the downstream flow.